# How to upload APK/Bundle to Firebase Test Lab through REST API?

Tags: android, firebase, rest, unity-game-engine, firebase-test-lab

I am trying to upload an APK/Bundle to Firebase's Test Lab to perform a robo-test/game-loop through scripts and not going on their website. I'm using C# and .sh scripts.

I see this link https://firebase.google.com/docs/test-lab/reference/testing/rest but I'm not sure how to utilize this information.

I am aware of the Google Cloud SDK (gcloud command) but I don't think I can use a CLI to do this since I cannot install anything.

Has anyone does this before? I've searched on the web and can't find someone who has done this.

Answer (score 0):

The specific REST API you want to invoke is
https://firebase.google.com/docs/test-lab/reference/testing/rest/v1/projects.testMatrices/create.

You can use the "Try it!" button to play with the API and see the http request body and response.

Google publishes client libraries for many specific APIs in several languages. I have not used this specific library, but here's the link to the client library that should be usable for .NET development:
https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/apis/testing/v1

It is a somewhat complex API. You might want to study the Cloud SDK (gcloud) Python source code for ideas on how to use it. But that would require you to install the Cloud SDK first, which you say you cannot do.

You could also study the [Flank](https://github.com/Flank/flank) kotlin code for examples of how to use the Cloud Testing API (and also the Cloud Tool Results API).